# Nunit Testcase on Select and Update queries

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, mocking, nunit, moq

I have written testcases for Database connection and select and update records.

Select Testcase -

```
 using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connection))
 {
      cnn.Open();
      cmd = new SqlCommand("AccessionDetails", cnn);
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CURRENTTIME", now));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TIMEINTERVAL", Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["interval"])));
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      da.SelectCommand = cmd;
      da.Fill(dt);
      Assert.IsTrue(dt.Rows.Count > 0);
  }
```

Update Testcase -

```
 using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connection))
 {
      cnn.Open();
      cmd = new SqlCommand("AccessionDetails", cnn);
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CURRENTTIME", now));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TIMEINTERVAL", Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["interval"])));
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      da.SelectCommand = cmd;
      da.Fill(dt);

       cmd = new SqlCommand("AccessionUpdate", cnn);
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACCESSIONID", dt.Rows[1]["AccessionID"].ToString()));
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       Assert.IsTrue(dt.Rows.Count > 0);
   }
```

I am using the same code where i implemented in the actual project code.

My select and update queries returns large set of values dynamically . So i cant not take single value and test it out in each Iteration.

My task is to Mock the above queries. Please help me in implementing the mocks.